FFMPEGWASM won't load version 12 reference error
I've written a simple script to load FFMPEGWASM but it gives an error:

Error loading FFmpeg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FFmpeg

Full code is here
<h1>FFmpeg Loading Example</h1>
<p id="message"></p>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.12.10/dist/umd/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
        const message = document.getElementById('message');
        try {
            const ffmpeg = new FFmpeg();
            message.innerText = 'Loading FFmpeg...';
            await ffmpeg.load();
            message.innerText = 'FFmpeg loaded successfully!';
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading FFmpeg:', error);
            message.innerText = 'Error loading FFmpeg.';
        }
    });
</script>


Does it still happen if you add the defer keyword to your ffmpeg script src? I'm guessing you're running into an issue where DOMContentLoaded is being met before the script is finished downloading. You may want to use defer, or load instead of DOMContentLoaded (and also put that script src line in your <head> instead).

@TylerH Good suggestions, I made all those edits and it still happens the same way
